# How to display 0 items in Table View for different users account with Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a tableview with Restaurants. Each restaurants  contains different types of food. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf52j.png) is my tableview for food in the restaurants, and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkFDZ.png) this is my Cart.
I want to make a "add to cart", so, when i'm tapping on the + button, it send the data from the curent cell to the database, and in the cart view controller it receives the data.
**The problem :**
My database is keep populating with items, and whenever ill open the app, it keeps recieving all the data, for all devices. How can i do so, when im sign in with another account, the cart to have 0 items.
If you need other infos, ask and ill edit.
Help please

Here s how im sending the data to the database when tapping the + button :

```
 func updateDocument(rootCollection : String, newValueDict: [String : Any], completion:@escaping (Bool) -> Void = {_ in }) {
                    
                     let db = Firestore.firestore()
                    db.collection(rootCollection).document().setData(newValueDict, merge: true){ err in
                        if let err = err {
                            print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                            completion(false)
                            
                        }else{
                            
                            completion(true)
                          
                           
                        }
                    }
                     
                 }
```

This is called in cellForRowAt

```
{
cell.didTapButton = {
            
            self.updateDocument(rootCollection: "CartDatabase", newValueDict: ["foodCart" : mancare.foodName, "photoKeyCart": mancare.photoKeyRestaurant, "priceCart": mancare.priceFood])
           
        }
```

This is what im using for retrieving the data in the Cart Table View
and called it in viewDidLoad()

```
func getCartProducts() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    db.collection("CartDatabase").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            } else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let newEntry = Cart(photoKeyCart: data["photoKeyCart"] as! String, foodCart: data["foodCart"] as! String , priceCart: data["priceCart"] as! Int
                    )
                    
                        
                        
                        
                    self.cart.append(newEntry)
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
             //  self.datas = self.filteredData
               self.cartTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to have a path component in the document path that specifies some identifier for the device; You could use `identifierForVendor`; so that different devices have different document sets

Comment: @Paulw11 Hello Paul, I spelled the questions wrong, I was gonna say when im sign in with another account.

Comment: Three things; First, you don't need this `DispatchQueue.main.async ` in Firebase closures. UI calls are always done on the main thread and networking is done on a background thread. Second; the code in your question doesn't have anything to do with the problem you're describing. [getDocuments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) will get the data once per call and not again; that is unless you keep calling that function over and over. The last issue is that call gets *everything* in the CartDatabase. If you want to get the data for one user, you need to add a query

Comment: @Jay so, what i need to modify if you can help me

Comment: It's kinda of a big question which is actually several different questions. If you want each user to have their own cart you need to change the design of your database; within the CartDatabase have documents tied by to the users uid (so the document id would be the uid). So a user with uid_0 had a cart in the database would be *CartDatabase/uid_0/items in the cart* so when that users logs on your code would read that specific cart and no others. There are other options but that's one. As far as your app continually receiving data, I don't know but its not the code in the question.

Comment: @Jay Hello, thank you for your answer. Firstly, yes, the function is called when the user press the + button. About CartDatabase/uid_0/items. uid_0 is the document and items are the fields ?

Comment: Sure. There are many ways to do it; one options is the documents have a document id, which in this case could be the users uid, and then the fields could be the items in the cart. Those could be stored a subcollection, or within an array or a number of other ways. Reading through [Add Data To Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) will probably help. The custom objects section may be applicable.